# Can i visit the U.S. while my H-1B is in process?

Tags: usa, immigration, h1-visa

I have a U.S. visitor visa, and I want to visit for a 1 week vacation trip with my friends. The problem is, my H-1B application is under process. Would it be OK for me to visit the U.S.?